# Ionic android ion-icon not showing

Tags: ionic-framework, ionicons

Since i used :

The ion-icon not showing on my android device, i did this for making work the firebase googleAuth !

Do you have any suggestion to make them appear ?

Thanks in advance,

ionic -v
6.16.3

Comment: Can you share the code of the ion icon please?

Comment: I have tried 2 solution this : 

<ion-icon name="compass"></ion-icon>

and then get the svg into my asset folder 
<ion-icon src="assets/svg/compass.svg"></ion-icon>

Answer (score 0):

be sure you have this in your **angular.json**:

```
{
  "glob": "**/*.svg",
  "input": "node_modules/ionicons/dist/ionicons/svg",
  "output": "./svg"
}
```

If still not working, you need to add this in your **app.component**:

```
import { fetch as fetchPolyfill } from 'whatwg-fetch';
window.fetch = fetchPolyfill;
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand why but ion-icon does not work when I migrate from capacitor 4 to 5.

I replace ion-icon by ion-img like this, before

```
<ion-icon name="chevron-forward-outline"></ion-icon>
```

after

```
<ion-img src="assets/icon/ionic/chevron-forward-outline.svg"></ion-img>
```

I download the svg from https://ionic.io/ionicons.

It's far from ideal but it works.